# Can we merge [ef-core] into [entity-framework-core]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently there are two tags for EF Core:

1. [ef-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core) with 85 questions
2. [entity-framework-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) with 2769 questions

[ef-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core) is a `suggested synonym` for [entity-framework-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) but currently has 0 votes and I'm not allowed to vote for that.

Comment: sounds like an easy edit to purge it.

Comment: @DanielA.White Please don't do that. We need community consensus on this stuff, and we need to be fixing everything when we're editing posts instead of just the tag, as well as we need to be closing and deleting any closeworthy or delete worthy content as well. Besides, if all we're going to do is swap the tags, there are tools abailable to CM's that prevent the disruption that editing would cause.

Comment: You don't even need a CM to swap and/or merge tags. Moderators can do that. Don't go on a manual re-tagging spree just because you're bored. If this is deemed to be appropriate, I can do it in a matter of moments. Right now, I'm not really seeing consensus.

Comment: I prefer a synonym over a merge anyway. Many people refer to Entity Framework by it's initials so a synonym is surely the better option, otherwise it will just be created again.

Comment: @DavidG For that you'd need new `[ef-1]`, `[ef-2]`, `...`, `[ef-6]` tags. What's the point of only having a synonym of a specific version?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Well using that argument you could have synonyms for `ef-6.2` and `ef-6.2.1` and so on which is clearly silly. I would probably not support `ef` as a tag as it's far too short and ambiguous though. Either way, the synonym has been approved so it's a moot point (for now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do it. It's about the same technology.

[ef-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core):

> Use this tag only for questions related to the Core implementation of
>   the Entity Framework, for generic EF issues use entity-framework tag.

[entity-framework-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core):

> New version of Microsoft's recommended .NET data access technology.

---

[entity-framework-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) should be the the main tag. It's more clear what it actualy means. However I find the usage guide of [ef-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core) better. Maybe we should copy this.

Comment: I'm not sure about copying the `ef-core` tag info. Isn't EF Core the next version of EF, that *happens* to be written in .NET Core? Calling it "the Core implementation" makes it sound like there are two implementations of the same thing.

Comment: As far as I know, ef-core is only for support of NET Core and is (at this moment) [**not** recommended](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/roadmap#critical-orm-features). If there is an option, EF6 should be used instead. I don't know if we have in future 2 versions of EF7 and EF-Core or one EF-.NET Standard. @Stijn

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I'd be stunned if EF7 was created. EFCore was originally called EF7 (and we already have that as a tag synonym here) so it would cause far too much confusion. Anyway, this tag synonym request has gotten my vote, we just need 2 more to get it approved.

Comment: Realistically, an asker who is using EF Core is not going to know whether their question is a "generic EF issue", and so the guidance in the `ef-core` tag is deeply unhelpful. If I hit an error in my EF Core application, I don't know whether I would've seen an identical error in EF 6 or not. If I want to ask how to do some task in EF Core, I can't possibly know in advance whether the same method will exist in EF 6. And even if I thought that testing stuff in another framework that I'm not using was a reasonable precursor to asking, I'm probably not even using an OS that's compatible with EF 6!

Comment: Additionally, my impression from having used EF Core (but not older versions of EF) and stumbled across lots of answers to pre-Core EF questions online is that the API has *drastically* changed. No answer I've ever seen to a pre-Core EF question has been relevant to me, at all; they universally use methods and properties that don't exist in EF Core. Conceivably there might be some high-level conceptual questions that are "generic EF issues" covering both pre-Core EF and EF Core, but I think the whole idea of a "generic EF issue" is mostly a confused one.

Comment: Given both my points above, I have downvoted this proposal for the suggestion that we keep the `ef-core` description. I agree that the tags should be merged, but the `ef-core` tag description is bad and should go away.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt That's entirely false. EF Core is **recommended** when .NET core and/or ASP.NET Core is used. I've been using it since 1.0.0-beta and since 2.0 it's getting much better. Of course, it still misses some of the EF6 fetaures, but most applications don't need them. EF6 and EF Core are different enough for problems unlikely to be generic to them. It's extremely unlikely that we'll see EF7 just as unlikely we'll see ASP.NET 5 (not core)

Comment: But, it's also not the "Core" implementation because someone might read that as "the core of the package" while it's an entirely new source code. I'd say it should read `Entity Framework (EF) Core is a lightweight, extensible, and cross-platform version of the popular Entity Framework data access technology.` just as the [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) says

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I certainly wouldn't use the MSDN copy. Much of it is tech marketing bullshit; I wouldn't for a moment call EF Core "lightweight" or "extensible" and have no idea in what sense they think those claims are true, the (subjective) claim the Entity Framework is "popular" is irrelevant here, and "data access technology" is meaningless marketing-speak that could just as well describe, say, JSON. Strip away the marketing, and you're left with the terser and more tone-appropriate *"Entity Framework (EF) Core is a version of the Entity Framework ORM that is compatible with .NET Core."*

Comment: @MarkAmery that last definition of yours still makes much more sense than the current on the tags. Do notice that EF Core is also compatible with .NET full