# Merge [ef-core-*] with [entity-framework-core-*]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

1. [ef-core-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-2.1) should be merged with [entity-framework-core-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-2.1)
2. [ef-core-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-2.0) should be renamed to [entity-framework-core-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-2.0)

Maybe we could also add synonym [ef...] to all [entity-framework...] tags?

Answer (score 1):

I support this proposal, which is strongly connected to the [already completed merge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356507/8528014) of [ef-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core) and [entity-framework-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core).

Affected tags and question counts:

1. [ef-core-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-2.0) (721 questions) / no equivalent tag
2. [ef-core-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-2.1) (499) / [entity-framework-core-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-2.1) (120)
3. [ef-core-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-2.2) (602) / [entity-framework-core-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-2.2) (83)
4. [ef-core-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-3.0) (411) / [entity-framework-core-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-3.0) (70)
5. [ef-core-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-3.1) (609) / [entity-framework-core-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-3.1) (110)

As the question numbers show, the shorter versions are used much more often. They also have some (rather trivial) usage guidance, which IMHO becomes redundant when using the long tags.

For clarity and consistency with the past tag merge of [ef-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core) and [entity-framework-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core), I'd vote for:

- Merging the [ef-core-*] tags into their [entity-framework-core-*] equivalents.
- Renaming [ef-core-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-2.0) to [entity-framework-core-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-2.0).
- (Possibly) creating usage guidance which advises to use the version-specific tags only when a question relates to a specific version.